# Creating a slurm job for ffmpeg

Tags: arrays, ffmpeg, slurm

I am new to building arrays in slurm, and am running into problems with my ffmpeg array.

I have an ffmpeg script that will convert all .mp4 files in a directory into folders of image stacks. Right now, I have to change to the source directory in the terminal (i.e., cd), and then run the following code:

```
for i in *.mp4; do mkdir -p "${i%.*}" && ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf fps=30 ${i%.*}/${i%.*}%05d.jpeg -hide_banner; done
```

I have 100+ folders of videos that I would like to run this code on. Rather than using "cd (directory name)" and then the above code, I would like to create a job array that will iterate through all of the folders of videos. I've been playing with the following array script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=sortvids_test
#SBATCH --partition=cas
#SBATCH --output=%x_%A_%a.out   # Output file (stdout)
#SBATCH --error=%x_%A_%a.err    # Error file (stderr)
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=my.email@email.org
#SBATCH --array=0-8:1

#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem=10G
#SBATCH --time=1-00:00:00

module load ffmpeg

# Change the following path if you want to process any other folder #Place_7.11 is the directory that contains all the folders of videos
scratch_dir="/scratch/user/my.name/Place_7_11_20230616_133418/Place_7.11"

folders_list=($(ls $scratch_dir))
folder=$scratch_dir/"${folders_list[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}"

echo "Processing folder: $folder"

cmd="cd $folder && for i in *.mp4; do mkdir -p "${i%.*}" && ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf fps=30 ${i%.*}/${i%.*}%05d.jpeg -hide_banner; done"

eval "$cmd"
```

When I check the output files, I will see the "Processing folder: $folder" command has the correct output. However, when I check the .err files, I see `mkdir: missing operand` repeated for as many videos exist in the folder. I believe the issue is that I'm not correctly specifying the input, or changing directories, but I have not idea how to fix this. Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why do you use `eval`?

Comment: I think you have a quoting problem in `cmd`